# ckeditor getData() doesnt seem to work as it should

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

First off I'll start off by saying I am new to javascript so hopefully this isn't a complete face palm question. That being said, the following code should alert the value of the editor when the user clicks off of it.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function openEditor(){
html = "Hello World";
config = {
startupFocus : true
};
editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'textBox', config, html );


 if (editor) {
    editor.on('blur', function(event) {
        var ckvalue = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData();
        alert(ckvalue);
    });
 }
}
</script>
<html>
<a href='#' onclick='openEditor()'>Open Editor</a><br />
<div id='textBox'></div>
</html>
```

Instead google chrome console reports:

`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getData' of undefined "`

Now when I change

```
var ckvalue = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData();
```

to

```
var ckvalue = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();
```

It works. This baffles me because I never declared a editor1 instance. I was hoping someone with a little more experience could explain to me why editor1 works when editor doesnt.

Here is a working example of what Im talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/s3aDC/6/

Comment: Can you post your code or a proof of concept? Hard to tell with the small amount posted.

Comment: [Here is proof of concept](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline)

Comment: Looks like you've added your code above which may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`editor` is a JS variable that points to `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1`. See that `editor === CKEDITOR.instances.editor1 // true`.

Moreover, event callback is executed in `editor` context, so `this` points to `editor`:

```
editor.on('blur', function(event) {
    var ckvalue = this.getData();
    alert(ckvalue);
});
```

And you can define it when initializing the editor:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'textBox', {
    on: {
        blur: function( event ) {
            console.log( this.getData() );
        }
    }
} );
```

And you should definitely [avoid global variables](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes) in your code! ;)

Comment: I changed the line to: var ckvalue = this.getData(); and now it works like a charm. I'll have to remember not to use global variables. Thanks for the quick and informative reply!

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor gets editor name from:

1. id or name attribute of textarea/editable element if editor isn't in "append to" mode: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/editor.js#L71
2. function that generates unique editors names https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/editor.js#L97

In your case editor is created by `appendTo()` method so CKEditor automatically generate name which is `editor1`, then `editor2`, etc. `CKEDITOR.instances` object contains all editor instances under their name, that's why there exists `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1`.

You assigned editor instance to global `editor` variable. But that's something completely  different than editor name - you can have editor instance assigned to as many variables as you wish.

BTW. You should declare variables with `var` statement before using them.