# Can I add data to an already serialized array?

Tags: jquery, serialization

I am using CKEditor and would like to serialize the textarea data along with all of the other elements. Is this possible?

I would like to append the taData to vals if possible.

```
var vals = $("#post").find('input,select').serialize();
var taData = CKEDITOR.instances.ta1.getData();
```

Comment: Well... `.serialize` returns a string. You can always modify the string if that is what you want to know. But maybe you are more interesting in `.serializeArray()`: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/.

Comment: Thanks Felix. Can you please show me how to do that? I'm JQ illiterate.

Comment: well, serialize main motto was to get values from whole the form and make it string! e.g. ?name=user&password=heart

Comment: OK, so then I really can't append the textarea data to the 'vals' string, right?

Comment: get the textarea value using val() function

Comment: @AspiringAqib. It won't work that way. I have to use CKs getData method to do that. I've already tried.

Comment: see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062654/ckeditor-getdata-doesnt-seem-to-work-as-it-should

Comment: i am concerned with jQuery only and not with CKeditor and i don't know what is getData :D

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627936/jquery-post-with-serialize-and-extra-data.

Comment: Thank you Felix, this seems to be what I need.

Comment: If you don't send the data via any of the Ajax methods, you can serialise the array later using `$.param`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/.

Comment: Thanks Felix. Using the post you linked to, what I get is a bunch of `[object Object]`. Is there a way for me to change that back into a query string?

Comment: I wrote a proper answer... don't use `alert` to inspect variables. `[object Object]` is the default string representation of objects. Rather use `console.log` and yes, you can use `$.param` to create a string, just as `.serialize` does.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`.serialize` returns a string, so you can always modify the string, but I would not recommend this, string manipulation can get messy.

Instead, use [`.serializeArray` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) to create an array representation of the data and then add the data to it. Each element of the array is an object with a `name` and `value` property:

```
var vals = $("#post").find('input,select').serializeArray();
vals.push({name: 'nameOfTextarea', value: CKEDITOR.instances.ta1.getData()});
```

All jQuery Ajax methods will understand this structure and serialize the data properly. In case you want to create a serialized string (just like `.serialize`), you can pass the array to [`$.param` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

```
var query_string = $.param(vals);
```

Comment: Thanks Felix, same to you my friend!