# How to add additional key and the value to json array

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting my form data in to a array with

```
var fields = $(this).serializeArray();
```

I want to push the dynamic token value  to this array before I make ajax call to process this array in php.

I try with

```
fields.push({token:value});
```

my ajax call to php is

```
$.ajax({

    type : 'POST',
    url : "test.php",
    data : fields,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data) {......},
    error{....}
});
```

In my test.php page I want to use that token value like

```
 $token = $_POST[token];
```

but the $token value is null.

Comment: ..........and what happens?

Comment: I am getting $token as null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I add data to an already serialized array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102732/can-i-add-data-to-an-already-serialized-array)

Comment: You could have a look at the `serializeArray` function and how the array is structured: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.serializeArray` returns an array with the structure

```
[{name: 'name', value: 'value'}, ...]
```

So you have to add an object with `name` and `value` properties:

```
fields.push({name: 'token', value: 'value'});
```

Or if `token` and `value` are variables:

```
fields.push({name: token, value: value});
```

[Have a look at the **documentation** for more information.](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

I have already answered that in another question: [Can I add data to an already serialized array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102732/can-i-add-data-to-an-already-serialized-array).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fields[token] = value;
```

If you use `push`, you're just pushing a value onto the end of the array, and the last index will just increment.

Comment: If it would have been an object it would be `fields.token = value;`. It is correct

Comment: No! Whether you use dot notation or bracket notation does not matter. I assume `token` contains a string... do you use string keys with arrays? I hope not.

Comment: If I use this ajax call fails.

Comment: Why assume `token` is a string? `fields` is an array regardless... Token could be anything.

Comment: I don't assume anything. Topic poster is using an array and wants an item added onto it, apparently with a unique identifier.

Comment: You can add elements to the array this way **if and only if** `token` is a number. But the problem is that `fields` is an array with a very **specific** structure and it has to have this structure if you want to make it work with `$.ajax`. Doing `fields[token] = value;` does not keep the structure. See my answer.

Comment: @FelixKling that's blatantly wrong. arrays ARE objects in javascript, and you can add properties to arrays just like you'd add them to any other object.

Comment: @sgroves: I never said arrays are not objects (well ok, I wanted to point out that `fields` should be treated as array and not as plain object). You shouldn't add properties with non-numeric names to it like this. They will all be ignored by array methods. And in any case, even if `token` was a numeric value, it wouldn't help the OP. The array has a specific structure as I already said a couple of times.