# How to add and retrive additional data to serialize() in jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I'm trying to work on how to append some more values to the serialize method in JQuery.

snippet

```
// 
      var dataString = $("#myform").serialize();
        dataString.push({name:"type", value: "myvalue"});
//
```

On passing the values to ajax call page

I am using this additional data for my conditional check as

```
if ( $_POST['type'] == 'myvalue')
 {
  // on success code 
  }
else
{
   //On fail Code
 }
```

But the condition is always going to else but now in if condition, Please assist If I am missing something and taking it wrong.

**NOTE the code is working fine if I am passing this name and value as hidden field form form ...

Comment: Have you tried dumping the $_POST array and see how it looks like?

Comment: and [Can I add data to an already serialized array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14102732/218196)

Comment: `.serialize()` method returns String, whereas `.push()` is method of Array

Comment: ya its not passing the value at all.. then where I am not able to do good at first place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

```
var dataString = $("#myform").serializeArray();
dataString.push({
    name: "type",
    value: "myvalue"
});
```