# jQuery AJAX - push additional key/value pair into a serialized $_POST array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

Is it possible to push additional values into a seriazlized $_POST array before sending an AJAX request with jQuery?

This is the scenario:

```
$('#ajax-preview').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $('#advertiser-edit-form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
       type: 'post' ,
       url: 'ajax-action.php',
       data: formData,
       success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
           console.log(data);
       }           
    });
});
```

`formData` is a serialized $_POST array from a page with multiple key/value pairs. I need to add another pair programmatically, namely `ajax: true`.

I tried to pass this data set to the AJAX:

```
var previewData = {
    formData: $('#advertiser-edit-form').serialize(),
    ajax: true
};
```

Unfortunately, it changes the structure of data that is passed to the PHP script and, in consequence, the data cannot be processed as expected.

Comment: Cannot you `unserialize` your data, add your pair `ajax: true`, then `serialize` it back?

Comment: Note that checking for an ajax call this way is not very reliable as the user can manipulate it. Checking on the server-side - for example by seeing if a variable in your environment is set - would be more secure.

Comment: See also [Can I add data to an already serialized array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14102732/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the $(form).serialize() just return a string so you can simply concat with the value you want to add.
Example :

```
var formData = $('#advertiser-edit-form').serialize();
// Be sure that formData is not empty, if it's you don't need the "&"
formData += '&foo=bar';
```

https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Then use the .serializeArray() function, then push the content you want to add to it. You can call the toString function after having pushed the value to have it as a string
https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: This is the right answer, thank you. I also introduced another check to determine if the current request is AJAX with `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'` so now I'm checking for the presence of a value in `$_POST` array as well as `$_SERVER`.